# An issue with "flutter webview widget"

Tags: android, flutter

I want to create a very simple flutter app that shows a specific webpage (kind of "web page to app" thing). In the app there is only a Webview widget. I did everything right, the app is up and running in the simulator but when i'm installing it on my device (and two more devices i also tested) i get this error: "err_cache_miss". I guess the error is generated from the chrome becuase Chrome is actually the webview. This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'My App',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Nextouch By Prevail'),
      ),

    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted, // Enable JavaScript
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Base on your package i havent found **Webview**:
But i manage to get it load with the code below

```
 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
 
 void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
 }
 
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});
 
   // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final WebViewController controller =
         WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(
             const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams());
     controller
       ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
       ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));

 return MaterialApp(
   title: 'My App',
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Hello world'),
     ),
     body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

**Here the result:**

[image: The Result]

Comment: "webview_flutter" for android need minsdk 19( >= 19) to run.